# How to connect to a mongodb Parse-Server with the PHP Parse SDK?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have a Parse server running and working well with my Swift code. Now, I would like to connect this MongoDB server to my PHP code. But I can't find any documentation on how to do that.

For the moment, I have this code :

```
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
```

How to update it to add my server URL ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has updated their PHP SDK, there is now a new dedicated function to reference the server URL, which is the following :

```
ParseClient::setServerURL('http://your-parse-server.com');
```

Hope it will help someone else!

Comment: My php sdk version is 1.1.I am getting folowing error - Fatal error: Call to undefined method Parse\ParseClient::setServerURL().Can u help?

Answer (score 0):

**Since i was also struck with some issue and resources were scattered i have grouped them in this answer, i know it's just links but these are links provided by parse and wong be moved or removed in the coming future.**

I found this example 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

a little more detailed info about migration is mentioned here 
https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating

issues with the migrating tools can be tracked here
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki

there is a wiki page about this found here
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki

finally, thee whole blog exolaining it can be found here
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-server-and-the-database-migration-tool/